# Javascript constructor function in this variable returns error

Tags: literals, javascript-objects, javascript

I have a function that I am calling the following way but it returns `someVariable.clean is not a function`

Here is the code:

```
var someVariable = function() {
        this.clean = function(obj) {
            alert(obj);
        }
    }

    someVariable.clean('test'); //call
```

Any idea why it is happening, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your're not in ES5 strict mode, you'll add the function `.clean()` to the global object.

So, just calling `clean('test');` would indeed work here. If you want it like you described, you need to return the function an object.

```
var someVariable = function() {
    return {
        clean: function(obj) {
            alert(obj);
        }
    };
};
```

If you are in ES5 strict mode, this code would throw an error, since `this` would be bound to `null`. What the `this context variable` is referenced to, always depends on how the function is invoked. In your case, as described, `this` is either `window` or `null`.

It would also work, if you'd invoke your function with the `new` keyboard:

```
new someVariable().clean('test');
```

That is because, `new` makes the function a *constructor function* and `this` is always bound to a newly created object within the function.

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because `this` within the scope of the function is still `window` (just as it would be if you declared the `clean` function at the top-level).  What you want is:

```
var someVariable = function() {};
someVariable.clean = function(obj) {
    alert(obj);
}

someVariable.clean('test'); //call
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to initialize your **prototypical** class

```
new someVariable().clean('test');
```

If you want a flavor of static class then consider using literals:

```
someVariable = {
    clean: function(obj) {
            alert(obj);
        }
};
```

Now you can call your way:

```
someVariable.clean('test');
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very educating! Never heard of EC5 mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a property of the function. It's only set if you execute the function, and it's then added to the global object (which is still not what you want).

You should instead set it the same way as you call it:

```
var someVariable = function() {
    // ...
}

someVariable.clean = function(obj) {
    alert(obj);
}

someVariable.clean('test'); // call
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this for better approch also and to solve your error.

```
var someVariable = cleanfunction(id); 

function cleanfunction(id)
{          
    clean: function(id) {
        alert(id);          
    }          
}
```